# How to cancel a method registered with [performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

My problem is, at some point in my application I call `[performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]` but during the delay which can be up to 1 second several things happen that decide whether the delayed method should or should not be called, however, once registered, the selector can't be unregistered so it will be called anyway. I tried to put a flag, but because `[performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]` can get called several times in a second using one flag fails.

I guess I somehow need to be able to stop the specific method before it gets called. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget%3a) method will remove any such queued perform operations.

Comment: Looks like EXACTLY what I need, will try it right now. Thanks!